# Custom Edge Swipe Event in Windows (For Bottom Edge)

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I want to open an app or do something with a bottom swipe, so what can I do to get the event? It's like this: https://www.microsoft.com/zh-cn/videoplayer/embed/fc016fcc-2bb1-4294-b236-343e1a533401?autoCaptions=en-us

I tried using the [EdgeGesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.EdgeGesture) class in UWP apps, which provides events for [Starting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.edgegesture.starting), [Completed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.edgegesture.completed), and [Canceled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.edgegesture.canceled). But when I swiped at the edge of the screen, no event was triggered.

In MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    //ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();

    EdgeGesture gesture = EdgeGesture.GetForCurrentView();

    gesture.Starting += Gesture_Starting;
    gesture.Completed += Gesture_Completed;
    gesture.Canceled += Gesture_Canceled;
}

private void Gesture_Canceled(EdgeGesture sender, EdgeGestureEventArgs args)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void Gesture_Completed(EdgeGesture sender, EdgeGestureEventArgs args)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void Gesture_Starting(EdgeGesture sender, EdgeGestureEventArgs args)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Don't know if I did something wrong, can help me? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In desktop mode, the UWP application is a **window** application that makes it difficult to capture screen edge slip events, and `EdgeGesture` may work in tablet mode.

In order to adapt to the sliding needs of different situations, you can consider using `GestureRecognizer`.

Here I will give you a simple page for reference.

```xml
<Page ...>
    <Grid Background="White">
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```cs
private GestureRecognizer _GestureRecognizer;
PointerEventHandler PointerPressedEventHandler;
PointerEventHandler PointerMovedEventHandler;
PointerEventHandler PointerReleasedEventHandler;
PointerEventHandler PointerCanceledEventHandler;
private double startY = 0;
private double moveY = 0;

public GesturePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    _GestureRecognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
    _GestureRecognizer.GestureSettings = GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateY;
    _GestureRecognizer.ManipulationStarted += _GestureRecognizer_ManipulationStarted;
    _GestureRecognizer.ManipulationUpdated += _GestureRecognizer_ManipulationUpdated;
    _GestureRecognizer.ManipulationCompleted += _GestureRecognizer_ManipulationCompleted;

    PointerPressedEventHandler = new PointerEventHandler(_PointerPressed);
    PointerMovedEventHandler = new PointerEventHandler(_PointerMoved);
    PointerReleasedEventHandler = new PointerEventHandler(_PointerReleased);
    PointerCanceledEventHandler = new PointerEventHandler(_PointerCanceled);

    this.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerPressedEvent, PointerPressedEventHandler, true);
    this.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerMovedEvent, PointerMovedEventHandler, true);
    this.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerReleasedEvent, PointerReleasedEventHandler, true);
    this.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerCanceledEvent, PointerCanceledEventHandler, true);
}
private void _GestureRecognizer_ManipulationStarted(GestureRecognizer sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs args)
{
    startY = args.Position.Y;
}

private void _GestureRecognizer_ManipulationUpdated(GestureRecognizer sender, ManipulationUpdatedEventArgs args)
{
    moveY += Math.Abs(args.Delta.Translation.Y);
}

private void _GestureRecognizer_ManipulationCompleted(GestureRecognizer sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    if (moveY >= 50)
    {
        // Can be understood as sliding a distance
        if (startY <= 10)
        {
            // head to foot
        }
        else if (startY >= Window.Current.Bounds.Height - 10)
        {
            // foot to head
        }
        startY = 0;
        MoveY = 0;
    }
}
private void _PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);
    _GestureRecognizer.ProcessDownEvent(pointer);
}

private void _PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointers = e.GetIntermediatePoints(this);
   _GestureRecognizer.ProcessMoveEvents(pointers);
}

private void _PointerCanceled(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);
    _GestureRecognizer.CompleteGesture();
}

private void _PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);
    _GestureRecognizer.ProcessUpEvent(pointer);
}
```

Fingers, mouse, and pens trigger `Pointer` related events when they tap the screen. The purpose of the above code is to capture the `Pointer` event and pass it to `GestureRecognizer` for processing.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer)

Best regards.